# changing radio button text color in style

Tags: android, radio-button

I tried to change `radiobutton textcolor` as follows,(since `textcolor` in theme is not applied for `radiobutton`, I added it as separate style)

```
<style name="BlueTheme" >
        <item name="android:background">#B0E0E6</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/mystyletwo</item>
    </style>
    <style name="mystyletwo">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

> The problem is , textcolor is changed but the circle button
>   is not visible.

Comment: may be your colorAccent color is matching to background

Comment: Accent color is also white @AmjadKhan

Comment: on selection or deselection it is not visible

Comment: It is not visible at all. When I am launching app, it shows only the text

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 <item name="android:tint">#ffffff</item>
```

(or)

**you can try this**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtn_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonTint="@color/primary" />
```

**(or)
 add parent theme**

```
 parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
```

please add this line your style.

Comment: Thanks.But there is no change.

Answer (score 3):

Try this use **[`android:buttonTint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#attr_android:buttonTint)**

> Tint to apply to the button graphic.
>
> May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Actually it is for api>=21 right? . And I tried it in style but it doesn't work

Comment: @Joe use `app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"`

Comment: @Joe can u explain why u select other user ans

Comment: @GowthamanM nothing wrong in your ans i'm just asking him about his https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863018/changing-radio-button-text-color-in-style/47863054?noredirect=1#comment82691022_47863054 this comment

Comment: @Nilu adding `parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"` solved my issue. That's why.

Comment: I used  `android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"` . not  `apps:buttonTint` . That's why I commented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863018/changing-radio-button-text-color-in-style/47863054?noredirect=1#comment82691022_47863054) Thanks for your answer!!!